# Exception has occurred: TypeError 'NaTType' object is not callable

Tags: python, greenplum, data-lake

I use a python dataframe to transfer the data from the data lake to GP envt. I have a column with the data type "DateTime".

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pds
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


alchemyEngine   = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user_name:Host:5432/warehouse')
dbConnection    = alchemyEngine.connect()

script = '''SELECT name,lastrun_date FROM Table'''

dataFrame       = pds.read_sql(script, dbConnection)
dbConnection.close()

conn= psycopg2.connect(host = hostname,
                dbname = database,
                user = username,
                password = pwd,
                port = port_id)
curr=conn.cursor()

for i in dataFrame.index:
    script_insert = '''insert into Schema.destination_table 
    (name,last_run) 
    values (%s,%s)'''
    val = (str(dataFrame['name'][i]), str(dataFrame['parsed_ts'][i]))
    curr.execute(script_insert,val)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Getting the error

> "object is not callable"

. I have tried replacing `str(dataFrame['parsed_ts'][i])`  WITH  `str(dataFrame['parsed_ts'][i]('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

It throws the error:  Exception has occurred: TypeError 'NaTType' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

The Error `TypeError 'NaTType' object is not callable` appears because you are trying to call a null value as a function.

In the line `str(dataFrame['parsed_ts'][i]('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`, the part `dataFrame['parsed_ts'][i]` is returning a null value and you are trying to access its property `('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, which is wrong. If you want to transform the format of your timestamps, try handling the null values first and then wrangling the timestamps with [datetime.strptime and/or datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), according to how the data is presented in your dataset.